# I'm not able to connect to Internet using the eth0 network interface produced by the pugable usb to eth adapter

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager, ethernet, devuan

Let's make a jump in the past,coming back to the network configuration of the old ARM Chromebook model xe303c12. Today I've bought the "pugable usb to ethernet adapter" and yes,I think that it may work out of the box. Infact I can see that when plugged in,Linux is able to create the network adapter,called "enx8cae4cd6c871" (renamed to eth0) and the device is listed between the dmesg messages :

```
# dmesg | grep eth0

[1.416705] ax88179_178a 4-1:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-xhci-hcd.1.auto-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 8c:ae:4c:d6:c8:71
[3.773464] ax88179_178a 4-1:1.0 enx8cae4cd6c871: renamed from eth0
```

this is the /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ethernet-eth0.nmconnection :

```
[connection]

id=Ethernet
uuid=cef595d5-43d9-4ae3-b5d4-55920ebdee39
type=ethernet
interface-name=eth0

[ethernet]
mac-address=8C:AE:4C:D6:C8:71

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]
```

Do you see some mistakes ? this is how looks eth0 :

```
enx8cae4cd6c871: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
ether 8c:ae:4c:d6:c8:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I tried :

```
# dhclient enx8cae4cd6c871
```

but an IP is not assigned and I'm not connected to the Internet using that adapter.

It makes no difference to add this to /etc/network/interfaces or not :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0 (or enx8cae4cd6c871)
iface eth0 (or enx8cae4cd6c871) inet dhcp
```

you may consider useful to know this :

```
# nmcli d s

DEVICE TYPE STATE CONNECTION

mlan0 wifi collegato ziomario (connected)
lo loopback connected (externally) lo (connected)
p2p-dev-mlan0 wifi-p2p disconnesso -- (disconnected)
enx8cae4cd6c871 ethernet non disponibile -- (not available)
sit0 iptunnel non gestito -- (not managed)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the interface is not renamed *to* `eth0`.

The kernel initially uses the name `eth0`, but the system renames the inteface from `eth0` to `enx8cae4cd6c871`.

This is because if you unplug the USB network adapter and then plug it into another port, it might then be called `eth1`... and so on. For USB network adapters, using the MAC address of the interface is the only (almost) sure way to assign an unique, persistent name to the interface.

To make your NetworkManager configuration to use the correct device name, you could run:

```
nmcli c modify eth0 connection.interface-name enx8cae4cd6c871
```

Completely separate from that, you might want to rename the connection to something other than the misleading `eth0`:

```
nmcli c modify eth0 connection.id Asix-USB
```

If you don't like the new interface naming scheme, you should add the kernel boot parameter `net.ifnames=0` on the kernel command line. How exactly that is done on an ARM device depends on the bootloader it uses: on ARM devices, the bootloader might or might not be GRUB.

Of course, you are free to assign a more human-friendly name to the interface if you want to. Just don't use the `ethN` form, because those might interfere with hardware autodetection as the network interfaces will still use those names for an instant before a more permanent name can be assigned.

---

Your `ifconfig` output:

```
enx8cae4cd6c871: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
```

indicates the network interface is `UP` but not `RUNNING`. So the adapter is powered on but (most likely) is not detecting a link signal from the other end of the network cable. The Network Manager status `non disponibile` (the exact English version seems to be `unavailable`) suggests the same thing.

The command `ethtool enx8cae4cd6c871` should provide a more verbose description of the state of the network adapter, with the most basic point on the last line. I would guess it says `Link detected: no` (or something similar). Any other information displayed depends on the capabilities of the adapter and its driver.

Does the network adapter have any LEDs? If it has, and they are all dark, that would also be an indication of no connection.

The network cable or the port you're plugging it into might be broken: try another network cable, or move the far end of the cable into a different network port if possible.

The picture you linked in the comments was frankly a waste of effort: the single line `enx8cae4cd6c871: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>` actually provided more useful troubleshooting information than the entire picture.

Comment: I have changed this : interface-name=eth0 to this : interface-name=enx8cae4cd6c871 inside the file called : /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ethernet-eth0.nmconnection and I've rebooted the machine. Unfortunately it does not get an IP address from the DHCP server ; I have also tried to set it manually,but I can ping only the IP that I have assigned,not for example google.com. And yes,I have fixed the resolv.conf file. Can you give a look at this picture ? https://ibb.co/5jwV3s7 ; thanks.

Comment: I've fixed the problem with the ethernet adapter. Now I get the connection from this and not from the wi-fi adapter. The eth cable was broken.